# Accessing enum variable declared within a Structure in C++

Tags: c++, enums, nested, structure

This is the structure, defined as shown in the following code snippet.

```
struct EPSecODSStat {

   uint64 flags;
   uint32 maxPause;
   uint32 timeToAutoFinish;
   uint64 scanned;
   uint64 lowResourceSkipped;
   uint64 aclSkipped;
   uint64 sharingSkipped;
   uint64 otherSkipped;
   EPSecODSState state;
   uint32 elapsedTime;
}
```

odsStat is pointer to structre EPSecODSStat..

```
enum EPSecODSState {
   EPSEC_ODS_RUNNING     = 0x0001,
   EPSEC_ODS_PAUSED      = 0x0002,
   EPSEC_ODS_PAUSING     = 0x0003,
   EPSEC_ODS_FINISHED    = 0x0004,
   EPSEC_ODS_TERMINATING = 0x0005,
   EPSEC_ODS_READY       = 0x0006,
} EPSecODSState;
```

Now how do I access the members of the enum using the structure EPSecODSStat? Can any one please help me out through this one..

Comment: Where is the enumeration `EPSecODSState` defined? Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you have and have tried to show us. Also please  read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: it is defined in the header file..

-sorry for the incomplete information

Comment: I marked this off-topic because it is not asking for a specific behavior or it is unclear what results the op would like.

Comment: my doubt is..

how do i access the enum variables through the pointer of the structure..??

Comment: Do you mean `EPSEC_ODS_RUNNING`, `EPSEC_ODS_PAUSE` ... when you say "enum variables"?

Comment: Also: Is the ***type*** `enum EPSecODSState` defined inside a `struct` or `class` or `namespace`?

Comment: @J.Doe yes..correct

Comment: What is correct? That `enum EPSecODSState` is defined inside a `struct` or ...?

Comment: J.Doe  .       yes both are correct..

Comment: Then show the definition of the `struct` that contains the definition of the `enum`. Btw: `EPSEC_ODS_RUNNING`, `EPSEC_ODS_PAUSE` ... are called "enumerators".

Answer (score 1):

You can access the enumeration variable by creating an object of the structure and using (object).state

In fact any member of a structure can be accessed using its object and '.' operator.

Comment: my doubt is.. how do i access the enum variables through the pointer of the structure..??

Comment: Provided that the pointer variable is pointing to a structure object. You can use the -> operator to access it's members.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> enum EPSecODSState {
>    EPSEC_ODS_RUNNING     = 0x0001,
>    EPSEC_ODS_PAUSED      = 0x0002,
>    EPSEC_ODS_PAUSING     = 0x0003,
>    EPSEC_ODS_FINISHED    = 0x0004,
>    EPSEC_ODS_TERMINATING = 0x0005,
>    EPSEC_ODS_READY       = 0x0006,
> } EPSecODSState; // <<== here
> ```

You are defining a variable named `EPSecODSState` of type `enum EPSecODSState`. This variable will hide the type EPSecODSState so you will have to use

```
enum EPSecODSState foobar;
```

to define another variable of type `EPSecODSState`. I don't think that this was intentional and that you maybe wanted to write

```
typedef enum EPSecODSState {
   EPSEC_ODS_RUNNING     = 0x0001,
   EPSEC_ODS_PAUSED      = 0x0002,
   EPSEC_ODS_PAUSING     = 0x0003,
   EPSEC_ODS_FINISHED    = 0x0004,
   EPSEC_ODS_TERMINATING = 0x0005,
   EPSEC_ODS_READY       = 0x0006,
} EPSecODSState;
```

which is a regularly seen pattern in C but unnecessary in C++. That being said, with your version of the `enum` definition you'd have to write

```
struct EPSecODSStat {
   //...
   enum EPSecODSState state;
   //...
};
```

When you have an instance of `EPSecODSStat` you can access `EPSecODSStat::state` like this:

```
EPSecODSStat epsecodsstat
epsecodsstat.state = EPSEC_ODS_PAUSING;
```

> how do i access the enum variables through the pointer of the structure.

If you have a pointer to this instance

```
EPSecODSStat *odsStat = &epsecodsstat;
```

you can access it using the arrow operator (`->`):

```
odsStat->state = EPSEC_ODS_PAUSING;
```

The arrow operator is just syntactic sugar for

```
(*odsStat).state
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your term "enum *variables*". The enum values are *not* variables, they are basically just named constants. The *structure* have member variables, and you access them as usual.

The enumeration values you use basically the same way as integer literals or macros.

For example, lets say you have

```
EPSecODSStat *pointer_to_struct;
```

Then (once you've initialized the pointer) you could set the state simply by doing

```
pointer_to_struct->state = EPSEC_ODS_RUNNING;
```

That of course requires that the enumeration is defined in the global scope.

Comment: getting this..

error: 'EPSEC_ODS_RUNNING' was not declared in this scope

Comment: @omkargaikwad Then please, as I commented, try to to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us. And read the last line in my answer.